# Express request.body is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes

This is my code and whenever I send a post request using postman or cURL I get an empty body

```js
const express= require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000)
```

[image: screenshot postman]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqygG.png

Comment: Did you make the change before or `AFTER` starting the server?
This looks like should work, but any change you make to the express server will always need to be restarted.

Comment: I just tried your code and it's working as expected, the sent body is returned in the response.

Comment: Probably you have to restart app for changes to take effect

Comment: do you have `Content-Type: application/json`?

Answer (score 0):

check your html form name tag. if name tag missing you will not get data from on req.body.

`<input name="example" id="example1" />`